# Adding default_scope to every model in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, models, default-scope

I'm trying to add a "default_scope" for all models in my project:

```
default_scope where(:deleted => false)
```

Is there any way to add this default_scope for all models automatically?

Maybe using Modules?

Comment: I see what you're going for here, but be wary. It can be dangerous to override Rails's definition of deletion (not to mention confusing to future developers), and it's also dangerous to add this scope to every single model in your app — what if you one day have a model that doesn't need this pseudo-deletion feature? It'd be kinda silly to add a boolean `deleted` field to it just to appease the default scope on all models, and the database would do extra work on every load. Meh. Food for thought.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, closest I can think of is deriving the models from the same class, for which this scope applies for.